# VBA: Power of a variable returns execution error 5

Tags: vba

The simplest problems can drive crazy. I want to do the power of a bracket with a variable inside in VBA. The "^" or "Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(x, y)" doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
Function lapseMil(v As Double)
    a = v / 1125 - 0.5
    lapseMil = a ^ 1.5 
End Function
```

Of course if I replace "a" by a value everything is fine.

Comment: if it indefinitely refuses to work, just multiply the square root of `a` with `a`

Comment: Sqr(a) also refuses to work (and a ^0.5)

Comment: You're getting an error because `a` is negative.

Comment: That's what I just realized, It worked for -0.5 ^1.5 so I assumed it was ok, but it is more (-0.5) ^1.5 which is not. Just need to find a workaround now. Thanks!